# How to create a column in SQL Server to hold different types of value

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012

I have a Table which needs to store data from dynamic fields of a form. During the usage, the final user should say the type of data he will input (text, numeric, datetime, etc) and input the value.

The UI is ready and when they decided the type, the input changes to the right format. Now, I want to know how can I store it into database.

Should I have one column for each type and store the value only in the right column?

Or can I have a column with a type like `TEXT`, store there and convert when read it back.

ps: I will have another column to hold the type of the value stored, like a enumerator value.

PPS: I'm using C# to read the data and to write it to SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: You could use a single column of the `sql_variant` type. However, having different data types for different rows may be a database model design flaw.

Comment: You could either serialize everything into a string (e.g. JSON), and store it in a `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` column - or alternatively, serialize everything into a binary format and use `VARBINARY(MAX)` for storage. Do **NOT** use `TEXT` - it's been deprecated a long time ago!

Comment: Take a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140518/best-way-to-store-a-value-which-could-be-multiple-types

Comment: Thanks @AlexK, but I really think have one table for each column will be a crazyness thing, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best way is to serialize value and store it as text. Then u can make calculated property in your EF entity to deserialize it from text to correct type

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myEntity = new MyEntity();
        var someDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        myEntity.DynamicDataValue = someDateTime;

        var someDateTime2 = (DateTime) myEntity.DynamicDataValue;
        Console.WriteLine(someDateTime2.AddHours(1));
    }


    public class MyEntity
    {
        public string DynamicData { get; set; }
        public string DynamicDataType { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public object DynamicDataValue
        {
            get => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(DynamicData, Type.GetType(DynamicDataType));
            set
            {
                DynamicData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
                DynamicDataType = value.GetType().FullName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's looks like a good way to me. Can you store even HTML as content inside the value property?

Comment: Html is just string, so yes

Comment: I'm waiting for the acceptance by our team. Soon they answer me I'll answer here (if they argue or accept).